# Как отключить проверку на Unconditional jump в valgrind по умолчанию?

Tags: linux, valgrind

Нужно, чтобы Valgrind перестал проверять по умолчанию все `Unconditional jump`.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Unconditional jump? Вы имеете в виду «Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value»? Эту проверку не нужно отключать — это undefined behaviour. Просто пофиксьте баг.

Answer (score 1):

ответ из комментария:

---

> Unconditional jump

Вы имеете в виду «Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value»? Эту проверку не нужно отключать — это *undefined behaviour*. Просто пофиксите баг.